# An unusual cypher query challenge: finding intersections with nodes grouped by label

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am trying to find a general(ist) cypher query, without having to specify labels, that would achieve the following use case.

- A user can be linked to nodes, which represents user profile or activity. For example `(User)->[:HAS_CLICKED]->(Document)`, or `(User)-[:LIVES_IN]->(Country)`
- An advert can be linked to one or more of those nodes `Document-[:x]->Advert`

The catch is trying to find an efficient query verifying the following: **a user  must be related to at least one node of the same Label as the advert to see it**. The general schema would look like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have looked through intersection and union techniques in cypher, including `apoc.intersection` procedure but it does exaclty work in the case.

The database contains approximately 6M relationships and efficiency is of the essence. We always try to find a random ad for one user (query would always start with `MATCH (u:User{id:"1"})...`. I have written a ton of unsuccessful tests but I am not sure which efficient approach I could have for a problem like this. Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try something along these lines, a two step approach, subtracting the labels of the "tags" from the Ad of those from the user?

```
MATCH (u:User {id:'1'})-->()<--(a:Ad)
WITH DISTINCT u,a
WHERE 
     SIZE(apoc.coll.subtract( 
                              [(a)-->(tag) | labels(tag)[0]],
                              [(u)-->(tag)<--(a) | labels(tag)[0]]
                            )
         ) = 0
RETURN a,rand() AS rand
ORDER BY rand LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Seems a very interesting approach although performance whise the first MATCH would collect nealry all ads... But i can try to work around that idea... ! Tks!

Comment: Why do you think that the first match would collect nearly all ads ? I assume the number of "tags" of a user is limited, so it would only collect the ads having at least 1 "tag"in common with the user.

Comment: On the contrary, it grows as the activity of users and the user base grows.... You are right though, it would collect "only" 1 tag in common, but in practice it can come to a lot in the end.

Comment: I have wrapped my head around it and tested it. It's exactly the thing i was looking for! No need to compare Ids because the are macthing "de facto". Now the query takes quite a long time, any lead on how that could be optimized ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple anonymous pattern match will get you results, e.g.:

```
MATCH (u:User {id:'1'})-->()<--(a:Ad)
RETURN DISTINCT a.id, ...
[ORDER BY] 
[LIMIT 1]
```

It would need profiling to understand how it behaves on your dataset, but it is unlikely to meet your efficiency needs.

Forcing the random sort order will slow the query down further, e.g.

```
MATCH (u:User {id:'1'})-->()<--(a:Ad)
WITH a, rand() as sortOrder
RETURN DISTINCT a.id, ..., sortOrder
ORDER BY sortOrder ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

If I try something similar on one of my graph databases (on an m5.xlarge EC2 instance), where there are about 35k 'u' nodes, 600k 'a' nodes and 17 million edges between them - when profiling I see 11,054,599 total db hits in 9852 ms!

The APOC / GDS path functions don't seem to meet your needs.
Though you could look at writing a user defined function based on e.g. [APOC's Neighbors code](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/4.2/core/src/main/java/apoc/neighbors/Neighbors.java)

How fast is the graph growing and how frequently is it updated?
Just wondering whether there might be other approaches (e.g. pre-computed graph embedding) that could help with your response time requirement.

Comment: Hi Robin, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately an anonymous pattern match does not address the problem since it would still return and ad for the first case (1st image), which it shouldn't.

Comment: Oh yes - I'd overlooked that subtle point. 
How many different types of advert targeting node labels are there?
Are they always mandatory?

Comment: Yep, it's an important point ! ;-)  There is ideally an infinite number of labels that can by used for targetting, the idea beeing that I do not want to change a query if I add a new targeting type label. That is what I want to achieve, but currently like more than 10 types. Yes they are always mandatory if attached to an advert (by groups of label though, as you guessed...)

Comment: I've got an idea for solving the mandatory labels challenge by determining the Jaccard similarity of the set of a User's neighbours labels (on the paths to the Advert) and the set of the Advert's target labels. Though I'll need to find some time to experiment with a Cypher implementation! Not yet sure whether it would work with the Graph Data Science library Jaccard implementation (https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/alpha-algorithms/jaccard/).

Comment: Hi Romain, Just revisited this and seen the answer from @Graphileon - that was the kind of thing I had in mind, nice idea to use apoc.coll.subtract to achieve the comparison.

Comment: Yep, it's a very smart idea I think! Thanks for your help...